# How to COPY multiple CSVs within a transaction?

Tags: csv, transactions, monetdb

I'm new to MonetDB, and I'm testing it for a high load analitycs app.

In order to load the DB beyond the initial load, I HVA eset a script that every 10 mins gathers the latest information into 2 CSV and COPY it into MonetDB.

Each COPY statement is transactional (you won't see the results until it's finished), but I want that if any of the 2 fails, be able to rollback both.

Is there a way to achieve this?